# CRTP against Function Overriding

Tags: c++, performance, crtp, overriding

CRTP is often suggested to avoid dynamic dispatch in C++, as a replacement for Virtual functions. However, one cannot access the derived class object with a simple base class pointer (without actually knowing the type of the derived object).

In this context, I am wondering, what advantages does CRTP offer against function overriding. To explain my point, I prepared the following example:

CRTP Way of defining a color group base class and a couple of specialization classes:

```
template <typename D>
class CG
{
public:
    void Green() { GetD()->GreenColor(); }
    void White() { GetD()->WhiteColor(); }    
public:
    void GreenColor() { std::cout << "This is a simple Green color" << std::endl; }
    void WhiteColor() { std::cout << "This is a simple White color" << std::endl; }

private:
    D* GetD() { return static_cast<D*>(this); }
};

class ColorGroup1 : public CG<ColorGroup1>
{
private:
    friend class CG<ColorGroup1>;
    void GreenColor() { std::cout << "ColorGroup1: This is Green Shade 1" << std::endl; }
};

class ColorGroup20 : public CG
{
public:
    void WhiteColor() { std::cout << "ColorGroup20: This is White Shade 20" << std::endl; }
};
```

The same class as defined above, but using function overriding, instead of CRTP:

```
class CG
{
public:
    void Green()  { std::cout << "This is a simple Green color"  << std::endl; }
    void White()  { std::cout << "This is a simple White color"  << std::endl; }
};

class ColorGroup1 : public CG
{
public:
    void Green() { std::cout << "ColorGroup1: This is Green Shade 1" << std::endl; }
};

class ColorGroup20 : public CG
{
public:
    void White() { std::cout << "ColorGroup20: This is White Shade 20" << std::endl; }
};
```

Now I can use the following code in two different programs, one using the CRTP defined classes and the other with function overriding.

```
int main()
{
    ColorGroup1 w;
    w.Green();
    w.White();

    std::cout << std::endl;

    ColorGroup20 p;
    p.Green();
    p.White();

    return 0;
}
```

The program result in both the cases:

```
ColorGroup1: This is Green Shade 1
This is a simple White color

This is a simple Green color
ColorGroup20: This is White Shade 20
```

So my question is:

1. Does CRTP offer any other advantage what function overriding does not offer ?
2. Is my assumption correct that both the ways offer equal/similar performance ?
3. If I were given a choice I would go for function overriding. What would you choose and why ?

Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: Firstly, I do not agree that we need virtual functions to override functions. The base class functions could be overriden in the Derived classes with the same signature. Secondly, just to clarify, my question was not about accessing the objects via a base class pointer but rather to know why cannot we simply override the functionality as given in the examples above, and achieve the same result as that of the CRTP example, with lesser code.

Comment: Using same signature to _override_ a non virtual method is not _overriding_, it's _hiding_. The two things are different in a lot of ways indeed.

Comment: Also, point 3 is primarily opinion-based.

Comment: OK. Its not overriding but hiding. But the question is still unanswered. Does any of you see any advantages/disadvantages of either of the methods.